# How to restore subversio 1.6 alias with XCode 6

Tags: xcode, svn, osx-mavericks, alias

My mac automatically installed XCode's update, and just after that, the alias that I previously set to use older svn 1.6 version (just like http://www.kevinmarkbroome.com/svn-1-6-command-line-in-os-x-mavericks/) was gone.

Does anyone know if there's a way to restore it?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to? the 1.7 client is compatible with older servers.

Comment: there are many people working on the project and no one will update  subversion also I'm not allowed to perform an svn upgrade. That's why I would possibly use the older version

Comment: You don't have to upgrade the server... you can use a 1.7 client on the existing 1.6 server, your colleagues can you 1.4 for all you care.  If you upgrade your working copy to the new 1.7 format it won't impact anyone but you.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply! I'll try doing this way.